# Can I import specific functions from other contracts and not the whole contract?

Tags: import, function

I am importing `Access.sol` by `OpenZeppelin` (`"@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol"`) in a contract. The main functions I am concerned with are `setupRole()`,`hasRole()` and `grantRole()`. Is there a way to only import these? When I spin up my contract it exposes other functions present inside the `AccessControl.sol` as well. I don't want to expose the rest of the functions present inside the imported contract to my contract because it might lead to some unknown behavior?
I read about `import {} from X` and did try it with the above mentioned functions but it gives me the following error :

`Declaration "grantRole" not found in "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol" (referenced as "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/AccessControl.sol").`

Any help is appreciated. Thank you for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the syntax `import {Y} from X` means that it will only import contract Y from X (if Y is the only contract it's like `import X`).

By only importing a contract it doesn't mean you expose anything.
You can't import specific functions and it's actually makes sense because these functions might depend on state variables (unless they are marked pure).

If you inherit from a specific contract you will get all of it's functionality, But not all will be exposed, there are private/internal functions also.

For importing only few functions I recommend that you copy them and the state variables they access.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to import only a few specific functions from a contract. You can make the parent contract an interface and only include the functions you want to import as part of it, so that you can just implement these functions in your child contract.